# I want to use unix command in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, unix, mingw, anaconda

It is a question of engineer 50's.
It may not be familiar to young people.

It seems possible to install mingw (gcc, gfortran) with Anaconda as below.
Conda install - c anaconda mingw

If possible, I would like to use the unix command (bash, vim, sed, awk, find, ...), is it in the list of conda?
I listed it in conda list, but I do not know at all.

If someone you know, please reply.

I used MinGW conveniently, but I'd like to introduce the recent topic Python (numpy, scipy, matplotlib).
It seems that MinGW has not been maintained recently.

What is replaced by the unix command (especially the shell environment)?
Powershell, bat file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [m2-base](https://anaconda.org/msys2/m2-base) in conda. The idea is, let's say you have anaconda install, you go the AnaConda prompt. Then you want to create a new environment with python 3.5 . You type this:

`conda create -n py35 m2-base python=3.5`

M2-base is not a perfect emulation of unix so it really depends what exactly you are looking for but worth giving a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those commands are part of the coreutils package. It can be found [here](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/coreutils).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But conda of windows version don't have it. It's for Linux-64 or Osx-64.

Comment: I found information (BOW)Bash for windows. I installed BOW and Anaconda to my Windows10. I'm looking forward to try it. My long time expectation may be solved by BOW.

Comment: There is another version of the package for windows (both 32bit and 64bit) in msys2 channel [here](https://anaconda.org/msys2/m2-coreutils). I also found one useful tutorial with good points about system path etc, check it out [here](https://www.oliversherouse.com/2017/01/03/unix-anaconda-m2.html) ;)